nextjs14 mongoose : Error: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"
I get this error when try to use mongoose with next.js 14.2.14.
// lib/mongodb.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
require('dotenv').config();
const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    };

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose;
    });
  }
  
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  return cached.conn;
}

export default dbConnect;


Error: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

I tried to set the connection uri directly to mongoose.connect but got exactly the same error
Also try to install dotenv and require it, but same error

Try logging the value of MONGODB_URI before the call to connect
